# Manually triggering a sleeping bash script which is waiting for a signal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, signals

I have a bash script which is sleeping infinitely and waiting for a signal handler to do some processing and then go back to sleep. My problem is that I want to trigger this script manually as well, and asynchronous to what's happening in the whole sleep-signal_handle cycle.

I'm wondering how to do this. Would the right way be to manually signal the script from command line? Can this be done while providing an argument? or should I run another instance of the script? The problem with the second approach is I fear synchronization issues when running two instances of the same script acting on the same data.

Comment: There is a few ways to achieve this. What are you using for signal handling in your script ? trap ?

Comment: How do you propose to receive a signal that has an argument?

Answer (score 1):

command line:

```
echo 'argument1' > tmp.tmp
kill -USR1 [pid of process]
```

script:

```
export arg=""
trap "arg=$(cat tmp.tmp)" SIGUSR1
```

The above is a total shot in the dark, next time please post code with your questions.  Thanks.